# Removing trailing slash with .htaccess within a subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having an issue removing trailing slashes using an `.htaccess` file *that exists within a subdirectory*.

Normally, this would be an easy fix, because there's already several solutions on Stack Overflow for a *similar*, but structurally different, issue. These solutions do not consider the `.htaccess` file existing in the sub-directory (as opposed to the root level).

For example, say I have the following file structure:

```
/subfolder/.htaccess
/subfolder/index.php
...
```

I want to remove all trailing slashes for requests after `http://server/subfolder/`. For example,

- `http://server/subfolder/file/` should redirect to `http://server/subfolder/file`
- `http://server/subfolder/news/12/` should redirect to `http://server/subfolder/news/12`

I currently have the following rules in `/subfolder/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Strip ending slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Pipe request to controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

With this rule, the above examples redirect to the following:

- `http://server/subfolder/file/` redirects to `http://server/os/path/to/subfolder/file`
- `http://server/subfolder/news/12/` redirects to `http://server/os/path/to/subfolder/12`

That is, instead of using the relative path from the `.htaccess` point (in this case, `/subfolder`), it's using the operating system's path.

I can remedy the situation by modifying the `.htaccess` to use `RewriteBase`:

```
# Strip ending slash
RewriteBase /subfolder
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Although this works, **this is not a desired solution** because if I move the files from `/subfolder` to `/newsubfolder`, I would have to edit `.htaccess` to `RewriteBase /newsubfolder`. That is, any time these files are moved to a different subfolder, the `.htaccess` file needs to be manually updated. Thus, the set of files would not be portable, because they would require *manual configuration* of the `.htaccess` file to use *absolute paths*.

I would like a solution that is more portable, one that can be dropped into any directory and work regardless of its absolute path. Preferably, this solution would not make use of `RewriteBase`, because from my understanding this cannot be set to the current sub-directory and must reference an absolute path.

I've spent several hours trying to come up with a solution, but most of the ideas I've seen involved using the root directory or involved some nasty hacks with environment variables. Any ideas would be fantastic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule in your subdolder's .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule /$ /%1 [R=302,NE,L]

# generate rewrite base dynamically
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]

# Pipe request to controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [L]
```

Comment: Your answer partially works. These rules fail if you have multiple trailing slashes (e.g. `/subfolder/slash///`) but it also more importantly fails if you are aliasing a directory (for example, from `/subfolder/public` to `/subfolder`, where `.htaccess` is in `/subfolder/public/.htaccess`).

Comment: Thanks for the update. Multiple trailing slashes are now removed. I still get an internal several (500) error with an aliased directory. This occurs due to the last line (`^ index.php`). This can be resolved by using `RewriteBase`, but do you have any suggestions for fixing the piping of requests to the controller?

Comment: What is the exact URL you use for aliased directory? Can you check Apache error.log for the reason of 500 error?

Comment: Thanks again for the follow-up. This URL would be the aliased to the following: `Alias /subfolder "/os/path/to/subfolder/alias"`. The internal error is not recorded in the Apache logs. However, if I change the last line to `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,R=302]`, I do notice that this gets redirected to `http://server/os/path/to/subfolder/index.php`, which of course is not valid and results in a forbidden 403 error which probably explains why there is an internal 500 error if we just pipe it without the redirect.

Comment: Try updated code. But I haven't seen any instance of 500 that is not recorded in Apache error.log

Comment: That works, thanks! I noticed that I had the error log level set to Warn, which would explain why I did not see it.

Comment: Thanks! But if the URL is the current directory the trailing slash remains ...

Comment: What do you mean by current directory in a URL?